# moving spinner value from activity to service android

Tags: android, string, service, android-activity

I am trying to move a value the user selects in the activity class to the service class so the service will run for that long. I understand I have to get the selected value from the spinner, do the math to convert miliseconds to minutes, and then pass that value to the service. It just isnt working for me the way I am doing it and I can not figure out why. I know that I cant pass string values as int values but when I try to make the values int it gives a syntax error to change back to string.

activity

```
    private static final String TAG = "ShipService";
public static final Integer[] TIME_IN_MINUTES = { 30, 45, 60, 180, 360 };
public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
public Handler handler = new Handler();
public Button button2;
public Button stop1;
public Spinner spinner2;

// Initialize the activity
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.ship);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    stop1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    stop1.setOnClickListener(this);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TIME_IN_MINUTES);

   adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
    int getTime = TIME_IN_MINUTES[spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()];
    long time = (getTime * 60000);***Gives error here***
    Intent intService =  new Intent(Ship.this, Shipservice.class);***Gives  
            error here***
        intService.hasExtra(time);***Gives error here***



}

// Handle button callback
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn2:
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting service");
        startService(intService);***Gives error here***

        break;
    case R.id.stop:
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping srvice");
        stopService(intService);***Gives error here***
        break;
    }
}
 }
```

Service

```
    public class Shipservice extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "Shipservice";
MediaPlayer myPlayer;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    myPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ocean_ship);
    myPlayer.setLooping(false); // Set looping
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Ship Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    myPlayer.stop();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    long time = 0;
    if (intent.hasExtra(time)) {
        time = intent.getLongExtra(time);
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Ship Service Started for" + time,  
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    myPlayer.start();
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your stacktrace for better undersatnding

Comment: I can not build the project with the errors it currently has.

Comment: Share what error you have seen.

Comment: where I am trying to move a int value from the activity to the service. I marked them as ***Get error*** in my code up top. it underlines them and wants me to move them from int to string. I am trying to get a value from a spinner in the activity class and pass it to the service so that the service plays for that length of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have logical flaws in your program. You are getting the spinner's selected position and creating the Intent in the onCreate, you should probably be doing this in the onClick so the value passed in is what the user selected when they clicked the button.

Also you're using "hasExtra" instead of "putExtra". hasExtra will only check to see if that extra is in and return a boolean. putExtra puts an extra in to be retrieved when the next intent starts.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

  int getTime = TIME_IN_MINUTES[spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()];
  long time = (getTime * 60000);
  Intent intService =  new Intent(Ship.this, Shipservice.class);
  intService.putExtra("timeToRun", time);  //putExtra instead of "hasExtra"

  switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn2:
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting service");
        startService(intService);

        break;
    case R.id.stop:
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping srvice");
        stopService(intService);
        break;
    }
}
```

Also when you pass the extras you need to specify a key you put them in with. I called it "timeToRun". You'll get it with "intent.getLongExtra("timeToRun"); You can't just put in the value without a key, as the Intent won't know how to retrieve it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. In the service class what do I need to change the if statement to?

Comment: You use the same key that you inserted the value with. Extras are just a key,value pair that gets passed to the new Intent.

Comment: so in this case theTORun is the key that should be put in the service as well?

Comment: the service class does not recognize timeToRun in the if statement in the onStart()

Comment: its working, i had a mistkey. Thank you so much I really appreciate it.